# Find Customers Who Shop at Multiple Stores

Tags: sql, teradata

I need a query that will give me a count of customers who have shopped at multiple store locations within the last 3 years.

I have formulated the following query, but it's not what I need to know:

```
SELECT STORE_ID, CUSTOMER_ID, COUNT(DISTINCT CUSTOMER_ID) as SERVICE_COUNT
From SALES INNER JOIN
     STORE_DETAILS
     ON trim(STORE_ID) = trim(STORE_ID)
WHERE (CURRENT_DATE - cast(SALE_DATE AS DATE format 'mm/dd/yyyy')) < 1095
ORDER BY 1,2
Group by 1,2
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT SALE_DATE) > 1
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: "it's not what I need to know" is not a problem description. What output does it give? Why is that incorrect or insufficient?

Comment: Is TRIM really needed? It's really bad for performance. What's the datatypes of STORE_ID in both tables? What's the datatype of SALE_DATE, actually a VarCgar or a DATE? Your date logic should be simplified to `cast(SALE_DATE AS DATE format 'mm/dd/yyyy') >= add_months( CURRENT_DATE, -3*12)`

Comment: Yes, TRIM is needed as the values are in two different tables and loaded from different sources.  STORE_ID is CHAR in both tables.  Often, the store_id has trailing spaces not allowing a true match. The datatype for SALE_DATE is DATE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want customers at multiple stores, then something like:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_ID
FROM SALES INNER JOIN
     STORE_DETAILS
     ON trim(STORE_ID) = trim(STORE_ID)
WHERE (CURRENT_DATE - cast(SALE_DATE AS DATE format 'mm/dd/yyyy')) < 1095
GROUP BY 1
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT STORE_ID) > 1;
```

I don't understand your date expression, but presumably you know what it is supposed to be doing.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.  Here is sample data and the expected results, however, I cannot format it correctly in my response to you.                                                        
Sample Data: 
STORE_ID CUSTOMER_ID
123 12345
456 67890
789 12345
321 67890
654 67890
987 67890
 
Expected Result:  
CUSTOMER_ID COUNT_CUSTOMER
12345 2
67890 4

Answer (score 0):

Optimized version of Gordon's query based on your comments:

> Often, the store_id has trailing spaces not allowing a true match

Comparing strings ignores trailing spaces. As long as there are no leading spaces (which is a worst case and should be fixed during load) you don't have to TRIM (it's quite bad for performance).

> The datatype for SALE_DATE is DATE

If it's a date there's no need for a CAST. Additionally the *within three years* logic can be simplified to avoid date calculattion on every row.

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, COUNT(DISTINCT CUSTOMER_ID) as SERVICE_COUNT
FROM SALES 
JOIN STORE_DETAILS
  ON STORE_ID = STORE_ID
WHERE SALE_DATE >= ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE, -12*3)
GROUP BY 1
HAVING SERVICE_COUNT > 1
;
```